# Does HTML5 video only work on an actual web server?

Tags: html, html5-video

I just want to practice by editing an html file on my local computer with image and video (ogv) files in the same local directory, but when I try to open a browser (latest version of Firefox) on the html file, it complains "No video with supported format and MIME type found". As I've been reading on the Internet, most of the solutions say to modify the .htaccess file. So is there no way at all to embed videos in an html file just on my computer (not running a web server) and get it to work?

Edit: What I have:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="media/gizmo.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
</video>
```

Another edit:
OK, it works on my local machine if I take off the `type="video/ogv"` so I guess I'll leave that out of the source tags while I'm working on my local machine and put it back in and do the .htaccess stuff if I ever actually put something on a web server.

Comment: show some html what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source tag of the video tag use

```
type="video/ogg"
```

That should work.

Even better make it as below

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="media/gizmo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="media/gizmo.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="media/gizmo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support this video
</video>
```

It will show a message for older browsers that do not support the `video` tag. The differenct video formats supplied because not all browsers support all formats.

Additional: If you are going to use a webserver, make sure the webserver also supports these mimetypes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though in my particular case, the exact opposite happened to work for my purposes. Your advice definitely applies when a real website is running on a real server.

Comment: did you check the mimetype text... my OGG is not equal to your OGV